# CheckBox Saved with IsolatedStorage (vb)

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have a problem loading the saved setting of a CheckBox (Checked True or False). On calling up the saved setting it always comes back as True from IsolatedStorage weather the CheckBox has been checked or not? Please see the code attached and I would appreciate it if someone could show me the error of my ways.

Kind regards

Will

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
```

'Rem Save Settings'

If CheckBox1.IsChecked = True Then

IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings("MyCheckBox") = CheckBox1.IsChecked = True

ElseIf CheckBox1.IsChecked = False Then

IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings("MyCheckBox") = CheckBox1.IsChecked = False

End If

End Sub

```
    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
```

' Rem Call Up Saved Settings'

MessageBox.Show("Choose Tank Procedure First")

CheckBox1.IsChecked = (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings("MyCheckBox"))

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Answer was kindly given to me by Karmjit Singh from the Microsoft Silverlight Forunm

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

```
  If IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("MyCheckSettings") Then
     IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings("MyCheckSettings") = CheckBox1.IsChecked
  Else
     IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("MyCheckSettings", CheckBox1.IsChecked)
  End If
```

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

```
  Dim x As Boolean?

  IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.TryGetValue(Of Boolean?)("MyCheckSettings", x)
  CheckBox2.IsChecked = x
```

End Sub